# Access value of variables

Tags: javascript

We can call variables by their names like this :

```
var name="a";
var a=4;
eval("alert("+name+")");//this will alert 4
```

But I heard that eval is not recommended. Is there a way to call variables by their names without eval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables are global, you can do `window[name]`, but otherwise, no you cannot that.  "Variable variables" is a PHP thing.

If you want to do this, change your program, so that your variables are stored in an object.

```
var vars = {
    a: 4
};
var name = "a";

alert(vars[name]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are right, `eval` is definitely not recommended. A common way is to make them properties of an object, and then use square bracket notation to access them:

```
var name = "a";
var myObj = {
    a: 4
};
alert(myObj[name]);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/K9DmF/).

Comment: +1 an exaplanation what this approach is solving - will be helpful :)